# Why can't react read google places api's "open_now" object property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-places-api, google-places

I am getting this error: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open_now' of undefined

```
render(){
   9 |     let ob = this.props.data.opening_hours;
> 10 |     if(ob.open_now !== undefined){
  11 |         console.log(ob.open_now);
  12 |     }
  13 |     else{
```

This is what I get back when i print out just the opening hours property

```
opening_hours: {
    open_now: true,
    periods: [],
    weekday_text: [
        "Monday: 10:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
        "Tuesday: 10:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
        "Wednesday: 10:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
        "Thursday: 10:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
        "Friday: 10:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
        "Saturday: 10:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
        "Sunday: 10:00 AM – 8:00 PM"
    ]
},
```

but as soon as I try to get open_now or weekday_texts, it gives me the same error. I can get access to anything inside the JSON object except that exact one. Is google's places API not working anymore? I was able to get the website, phone number and name, I'm not sure why it only crashes on opening hour
[image]

Comment: Obviously you are doing something wrong. Post more complete code. And your check should at least be `if (ob && ob.open_now !== undefined) {`

Comment: How are you printing just the `opening_hours` property?

Comment: thanks @dfsq , didn't know that was a thing in javascript, it works now,

Comment: @Tico i did console.log(result.opening_hours.open_now), that gave me the error, but when i did console.log(result.opening_hours) it printed that object. It seems like when i try to print something inside the opening_hours object, i got an error, but I think i got it solved

Comment: My understanding is that Chrome devtools console logs can be lazily evaluated, so if a variable's reference changes after a console.log, the log may be misleading. Either way, @dfsq's solution looks correct. You could also use something like lodash's `get` function for safe deep property access (returns undefined rather than throwing an error if any part of the chain is undefined).